# File sharing encryption in windows 7 and 8.1

Tags: windows, security, encryption, windows-7, windows-8.1

I want to know about file sharing encryption in windows 7 and windows 8.1. Scenario is I want to share file between two machines with enabled end to end encryption in flight. Now according to my research, SMB2.0 is used to share files and there is no end-to-end encryption in SMB 2.0 which means if network packet is captured without IPSec then content of file can be seen in READ RESPONSE packet. While in windows 8.1 and server 2012, SMB3.0 has been introduced which provides end-to-end encryption for on-flight file sharing.

Firstly, I have confusion in default security option for file sharing in windows 7 and 8. File sharing security can be enabled from 
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings
by enabling "use 128-bit encryption to help protect file sharing connection". What does this option do? With this option being enabled; if i capture data at network layer using wireshark, will it show me encrypted content of shared file?? Well I have captured and it shows plain text data. Can anyone tell me how this option works?

Secondly, I have shared file between machines running windows 8.1. here again in wire-shark captured packet details SMB2.0 is used. Can we enable SMB3.0 for file sharing between peers (running windows 8.1) so that files are end to end encrypted in-flight?? I have seen that in server 2012 the option of encrypted access can be enabled for specific shared folders but how this end to end encryption of SMB3.0 can be enabled between peers of 8.1??

Answer (score 1):

Win 7 do not support smb3 (i.e encryption) so Win 8/8.1/server 2012 will use it backward compatibility and use SMB2/1 when data is being shared with Win 7 and prior versions. 
A good solution for you is to replace the Microsoft CIFS with a third party CIFS provider that support SM3.